# Labeling a shape in Excel 2007 VBA

Tags: microsoft-excel, microsoft-excel-2007, vba, shapes

I've created a macro to make shapes using `AddShape`. 
I name it with `.name` but I can't put a label on the shape icon with the macro.

If you manually click on a shape you can enter a formula to place a label on the icon. I can't find a way to automate this in a macro.

```
Set myDocument = Worksheets(1)
With myDocument.Shapes.AddShape(msoShapeFlowchartConnector, _
    LCell, TCell, WCell, HCell)
    .Name = "Bin" & i
    .Select
    ' I would like to add the formula here!
 End With
```

(This is on Windows 10.)

Comment: How  would you normally assign a label to it using vanilla Excel? I don't see any obvious way to do so in either the right-click menu for a shape, or in the drawing toolbar.

Comment: For Excel 2013 there's the [Shapes.AddLabel](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff840497.aspx) method, but I suppose that doesn't help you much.

Answer (score 0):

By the simple trick of using "Record Macro",
I was able to generate the following code (in Excel 2013):

```
Selection.ShapeRange(1).TextFrame2.TextRange.Characters.Text = "This is my shape"
With Selection.ShapeRange(1).TextFrame2.TextRange.Characters(1, 12). _
    ParagraphFormat
    .FirstLineIndent = 0
    .Alignment = msoAlignLeft
End With
With Selection.ShapeRange(1).TextFrame2.TextRange.Characters(1, 12).Font
    .NameComplexScript = "+mn-cs"
    .NameFarEast = "+mn-ea"
    .Fill.Visible = msoTrue
    .Fill.ForeColor.ObjectThemeColor = msoThemeColorLight1
    .Fill.ForeColor.TintAndShade = 0
    .Fill.ForeColor.Brightness = 0
    .Fill.Transparency = 0
    .Fill.Solid
    .Size = 11
    .Name = "+mn-lt"
End With
```

The first line of the above seems to be enough to enter the text into the shape;
the rest, apparently, merely explicitly set the default attributes.

Comment: Thank you so much!  This not only answered this question but my next question also :)    (In excel 2007 recording a macro came back with an empty macro)

Answer (score 0):

I finally dug deep enough in the debugger to find `.texteffect.text` to get my desired result.

```
With myDocument.Shapes.AddShape(msoShapeFlowchartConnector, _
        LCell, TCell, WCell, HCell)
    .Name = ShapeName
    .TextEffect.Text = "My Label"
```